# Flutter TextFormField TextAlign.center Doesn't Make Input Centered

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing a little problem with Flutter UI which I'm not sure what cause it.

Here's my snippet:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  String fetchedData = 'doubleleng';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 40.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: fetchedData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 4.0,
                    ),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                        ],
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I want to build a dynamic TextFormField based on the length of the fetchedData so I use ListView.builder. I fill the textAlign property with TextAlign.center but doesn't get exactly what I want.

Here's the SS:

[image]

Here's the SS of the weird part (not exactly centered):

[image]

It's not just '5' but all

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a problem with RepaintBoundary or font itself, but
I tried a few things and see the only solution is to use InputDecoration with Padding in your TextFormField/TextField:

```
TextFormField(
// your params
   decoration: new InputDecoration(contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0))
)
```

Comment: I have done this myself but still think it's not the correct solution.